# Paperclip: Staging App that can read from productions bucket, but write to different bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I run a staging and development environment that is a mirror of the production database.

I use the Paperclip gem for storing uploads to S3. I want to let environments that are not production READ from the production bucket (because thats where the file is stored), but WRITE to a different bucket, for safety. In addition, the app should be smart enough to now READ from the different bucket IF an upload was made.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging I discovered that the `bucket` option for `has_attached_file`can take a proc.

```
config/inititalizers/paperclip_defaults.rb

LIVE_BUCKET = 'media'
STAGING_BUCKET = 'media-demo'

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  storage: :s3,
  path: 'assets/:class/:id/:attachment/:style.:extension',
  s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  s3_host_name: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  use_timestamp: false,
  bucket: proc { |attachment|
    (Rails.env.production? || !attachment.dirty?) ? LIVE_BUCKET : STAGING_BUCKET
  }
)
```

Relevant documentation:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Attachment#dirty%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

the way that I achive this is I have a config file local that is different from my config on the server I use Heroku to host my apps.

1) I create a file called **config/config.yml**

```
#S3
S3_KEY: 'xxxxxx'
S3_SECRET: 'xxxxxxxx'
S3_REGION: 'us-east-1'
S3_ASSET_URL: 'appname-dev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
S3_BUCKET_NAME: 'appname-dev'
```

2) I read variables form **config/config.ym** into **config/application.rb**
require File.expand_path('../boot', **FILE**)

```
require 'rails/all'
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

    module Appname
      class Application < Rails::Application
        config.before_initialize do
          dev = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'config.yml')
          YAML.load(File.open(dev)).each do |key,value|
            ENV[key.to_s] = value
          end if File.exists?(dev)
        end
      end
    end
```

then on `Heroku` I set the config variables

I hope this is able to help.

Comment: This is to specify the bucket per environment. I can do that easily with the bucket: ENV['BUCKET'] option for has_attached_file. I am looking to use a dynamic bucket based on whether its a read or write operation.

Comment: what you really need is just `KEY` and `SECRET` you can change the `ENV['BUCKET']` on the fly if you need, I was just showing you who i set my environment